# event on <tr> tag except paticular <td>

Tags: jquery

I have problem about *event handling*.

Here is example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='xxx'/><td>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='xxx'/><td>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='xxx'/><td>
        <td>a3</td>
        <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>
```

I *bind* **click** event on `tr` tag and then even when `checkbox` was **checked**, it called **click** event.

How do I except this?

It is not good to bind event on  tag. because, the number of td tag is not limited.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are using invalid html, unless you have a typo in your copying of your code.

Comment: Looks like your html is messed up `<td><input type='checkbox' id='xxx'/><td>` the `<td>` does not close.

Comment: you are using the same ID many times (`xxx`).

Comment: @varnie I'm sure his real Id isn't 'xxx'

Comment: sorry. i missed typing. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    //your code
})

$('table').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mLn6q/)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do, after fixing the messed up tags, is:

```
$("tr").click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is("input[type='checkbox']")) {
        alert("No checkbox");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your checkbox

```
<td><input type='checkbox' class="cb" id='xxx'/></td>
```

and use e.target to determine if the checkbox was clicked

```
$('tr').on('click',function(e){
var target=$(e.target);
if (target.hasClass('cb')){
     return false;
   }
});
```